# Setting rewarded video ads to 30 seconds

Tags: android, admob-rewardedvideoad

I have implemented a rewarded video ad in my application but it displays the ad in just 10 seconds. How can i code the program to set the ad to 30 seconds?

I am using gms:play-service:19.0.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. You can select which type of ads to show but you can;t set time .I think that depend on advertiser.